# OpenVPN and one way pings

Tags: routing, openvpn, ping

## Network configuration

I have set up a network:

[image: Network diagram]

Appropriate ports of computers in `192.168.87.0/24` are forwarded on `TP-LINK router` to be seen "all over the world".

IP forwarding in enabled on `OpenVPN server`.

I am able to connect from OfficeB from `client1` to `OpenVPN server` in OfficeA. `client1` and `server` see each other -- they reply for pings (both in `192.168.87.0/24` and `10.8.0.0/24` network), send data, create connections (i.e. ssh).

Routing table on `TP-LINK router` (`a.b.c.d` is a WAN IP):

```
DST             MASK                GATEWAY         IFACE
a.b.c.d         255.255.255.255     0.0.0.0         WAN
192.168.87.0    255.255.255.0       0.0.0.0         LAN & WLAN
10.8.0.0        255.255.255.0       192.168.87.2    LAN & WLAN (route added by hand)
239.0.0.0       255.0.0.0           0.0.0.0         LAN & WLAN
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0             a.b.c.d         WAN
```

## The problem

And now... From ANY computer in `192.168.87.0/24`, I can ping `10.8.0.6`. Unfortunately `10.8.0.6` can ping ONLY `87.1`, `87.2`.

But... `10.8.0.6` would start to ping a computer in `87.0/24` (for example `87.104`) only if I pinged firstly from this computer to `10.8.0.6`:

1. `10.8.0.6`: `ping 192.168.87.104` -- failed, time exceeded.
2. `192.168.87.104`: `ping 10.8.0.6` -- ok.
3. `10.8.0.6`: `ping 192.168.87.104` -- ok.

### What I've checked

I've checked with `tcpdump`, that `192.168.87.104` DOES always get requests send replies for pings from `10.8.0.6`. But the replies seem not to pass thru gateway `TP-LINK router` back to `10.8.0.6` -- I cannot see them with `tcpdump` on `OpenVPN server` on both interfaces.

I've also checked, that if I added a route on `192.168.87.104`:

```
(1) route add 10.8.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.87.2
```

then `10.8.0.6` would always get a ping reply, even if I hadn't pinged it from `192.168.87.104` before.

Another thing I've found out: pinging from `192.168.87.104` to `10.8.0.6` adds to routing cache (`route -C`) an entry `(1)`. And in the ,,first ping'' (before the entry is added) I get:

```
PING 10.8.0.6 (10.8.0.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.8.0.6: icmp_req=1 ttl=127 time=37.0 ms
From 192.168.87.1: icmp_seq=2 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.87.2)
64 bytes from 10.8.0.6: icmp_req=2 ttl=127 time=93.0 ms
```

I read, that this was a normal behavior, because the gateway to `10.8.0.0` was in the same network segment. And after `icmp redirect host` a new entry was created in routing cache.

The `TP-LINK router`, in web configuration panel, has a check-box `SPI Firewall - Stateful Packet Inspection`. Disabling it does not solve the problem.

## My question

I can't understand why a ping reply `192.168.87.104 > 10.8.0.6` does not pass thru `TP-LINK router` despite `TP-LINK router` knows a route to `10.8.0.0` and ping request from `192.168.87.104` to `10.8.0.6` does pass.

So my question is: what is the reason? Is there anything I can do to solve the situation (except for adding a route `(1)` on each computer in OfficeA...)? I, personally, think that a problem is in `TP-LINK router`.

---

`OpenVPN server` configuration file:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca keys/ca.crt
cert keys/server.crt
key keys/server.key
dh keys/dh1024.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.87.0 255.255.255.0"

client-to-client

keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo

persist-key
persist-tun
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the TP-LINK is initially dropping the ping replies from `.87.104` to `.0.6` because of a stateful firewall rule. Notice that when `.0.6` pings `.87.104`, the TP-LINK router never sees the ping request packets. From the point of view of a stateful firewall, it is perfectly reasonable to drop ping replies if it never saw the original ping requests going in the opposite direction. Later, after `.87.104` has sent some ping requests to `.0.6`, the firewall can allow ping replies from `.84.104` to `.0.6`, since it has seen `.87.104` initiate communication with `.0.6` recently.

It may be possible to modify the TP-LINK's firewall rules. But since it is a "budget" brand router, I suspect your options will be limited to something like a "Stateful Firewall on/off" check-box. Or you may not even get that.

One possible solution is to add a second NIC to the Debian OpenVPN server, and make it Office A's internet gateway router. That way, the default gateway route on Office A clients will also work for `10.8` traffic, and you won't have to add an extra entry to all clients' routing tables. And as an added bonus, you will have the opportunity to use `iptables` to tailor your firewall rules to your heart's desire.

Comment: Yes, this TP-LINK has checkbox `SPI Firewall - Stateful Packet Inspection`. I tried (I forgot to mention it in my Q.) to turn of that `SPI` -- but the problem still existed. And I also thought about second NIC :). Thank you very much: you've confirmed my ideas:) BTW. I've just setup the connection A-B with OpenVPN Ethernet Bridging (`dev tap`)-- it's working perfectly now.